Vite server not reloading on file changes after migrating from 4.4 to 5
I have a vue 3 vite application for custom web components.
The application builds the bundle and then the bundle is used in the index.html to run the custom web components.
When in development I use npx vite build --watch to detect any changes in .ce.vue files to trigger a rebuild that creates a new dist folder. This still works correctly to detect changes in .ce.vue files.
Since there is a new version of the build in the dist folder, previously when using the npx vite, the server detected the changes and restarted causing the index.html to server the latest bundle. However, after upgrading to version 5, it cannot detect changes in the dist folder.
How can I get the previous behavior?
The following is my vite.config.js, I have not changed anything since the upgrade
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  return {
    esbuild: {
      ...(mode === 'production' && { drop: ['console', 'debugger'] }),
    },
    server: {
      port: 3005,
    },
    define: {
      __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: false,
      __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: false,
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      },
    },
    plugins: [vue(), viteVueCESubStyle()],
    build: {
      minify: true,
      sourcemap: false,
      lib: {
        formats: ['esm', 'cjs', 'iife'],
        entry: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/index.js', import.meta.url)),
        name: 'evalufySdk',
        fileName: (format) => `evalufy-sdk-${pkg.version}.${format}.${mode}.js`,
      },
      rollupOptions: {
        external: Object.keys(pkg.devDependencies || {}),
        output: {
          plugins: [
            banner.default({
              file: fileURLToPath(new URL('banner.txt', import.meta.url)),
            }),
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  };
});

Tried using
server: {
    watch: {
      usePolling: true
    }
  }

tried vite-plugin-restart plugin
